# Tipping etiquette in different countries

Tags: local-customs, tipping

What are the tipping etiquette in different countries? How much tip should I give to a waiter/waitress?

Comment: My original question ( http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/229/references-for-tipping-etiquette-in-different-countries ) about references for tipping etiquettes has been closed by Joel since "we want answers, not links to answers". According to the relatively large number of upvotes such a tipping reference database would be useful, so I rephrase the question. Someone please change the question to community wiki.

Comment: This is an open-ended list question and as such is also discouraged on SE I believe. One option is to make it a "community wiki" but those apparently have some issues. Another option is to just ask about each place you're interested in separately.

Comment: Yeah. I wrote about [why this should be closed](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46/about-those-tipping-questions) -- the short version is it's not a genuine question... if you really wanted to know you would have typed "tipping" into Google and found a million exhaustive references.

Answer (score 5):

Kicking off with a few I know...

**UK:**

- Restaurants - 10% (but check the bill - it's sometimes already put on there, especially for big groups)
- Taxis - 10%
- Pubs/Bars - none

**France:**

- Restaurants - 5-10%
- Taxi - round up
- Pubs/Bars - none

**Australia:**

- Restaurants - 10% (generally only mid price - fancy restaurants only though)
- Taxis - round up
- Pubs/Bars - none

**USA:**

- 15-20% to almost everyone...